Wagon R Stingray Automatic creep not working sometimes
I have used Maruti Wagon R stingray Automatic 2017 model. I put the car in neutral with handbrake engaged while parking because it doesn't have parking gear indicator i.e. (R/N/D)
Sometimes I noticed after starting the car and shifting gears to N or D and releasing brakes car doesn't crawl automatically I have to slightly press gas pedal. This is not happening frequently but sometimes.
What could be the reason for this problem and how I can get this fixed?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

From you description, I'm not sure you have an issue? A vehicle with an automatic won't necessarily start moving when you've released the brake while the vehicle is in gear. It really is dependent upon the speed of the engine. Every automatic has a point at which the torque converter starts transmitting power to the transmission. If the engine is cold and running a little faster at idle, it may be above this point. If the engine is full warmed up, the idle may be lower and be below the grab point. Could this be what you're experiencing?
